# Template constructor can't be called

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I am implementing a class similar to std::list. I am having problems with the wrong constructor being called.

Here's a working code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class dslist
{
public :
    typedef size_t    size_type ;
public :
    explicit dslist( const size_type count , const T &value ) ;
    template <typename InputIt>
    explicit dslist( InputIt first , InputIt last ) ;
} ;
template <typename T>
dslist<T>::dslist( const size_type count , const T &value )
{
    std::cout << "count, value ctor" << std::endl ;
}
template <typename T>
template <typename InputIt>
dslist<T>::dslist( InputIt first , InputIt last )
{
    std::cout << "Iterator" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    dslist<int> l( 10 , 20 ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

If I run this, the iterator constructor is called. But, really the first constructor (count, value) should be called.

How to ensure that the first constructor is called in this case?

Edit to add the solution here extracted from the answer:

**Solution**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class dslist
{
public :
    typedef size_t    size_type ;
public :
    explicit dslist( const size_type count , const T &value ) ;
    template <typename InputIt, typename = decltype(*std::declval<InputIt>())>
    explicit dslist( InputIt first , InputIt last ) ;
} ;
template <typename T>
dslist<T>::dslist( const size_type count , const T &value )
{
    std::cout << "count, value ctor" << std::endl ;
}
template <typename T>
template <typename InputIt, typename>
dslist<T>::dslist( InputIt first , InputIt last )
{
    std::cout << "Iterator" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
    dslist<int> l( 10 , 20 ) ;

    std::vector<int> v( 10 ) ; 
    dslist<int> l1( std::begin( v ) , std::end( v ));
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `dslist<int> l( 10 , 20 ) ;`, the template constructor wins in overload resolution because it's an exact match. While the 1st constructor requires an impliclit conversion from `int` (the type of `10`) to `size_t` (an unsigned integer type).

You can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to exclude undesired specializations from the overload set. e.g. the iterator type is supposed to support `operator*`.

```
template <typename InputIt, typename = decltype(*std::declval<InputIt>())>
explicit dslist( InputIt first , InputIt last ) ;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yYfcXP52Pf3Qpeix)

Comment: And this is perfectly sufficient, since at least one of the arguments to the other overload never will.

Comment: @songyuanyao If I do something like this, std::vector<int> v( 10 ) ; dslist<int> l1( std::begin( v ) , std::end( v ) ) ; (in main). This results in an error. The above solution partially solves the problem.

Comment: @DevenTopiwala My fault. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values `10` and `20` are `int` of course the iterator ctor matches best. So:

1. You can add explicit casts (e.g `size_t(10)` or `static_cast<size_t>(10)` to invoke the correct one.
2. Create a user defined literal for `size_t` since there are no built in literals for this

Comment: If you look at the std::list constructor, it has the same constructor. And if I use std::list instead of my class (dslist), the correct constructor is called. I am trying to figure out, how the std::list works internally and how the first constructor is invoked for std::list.

Comment: @DevenTopiwala If we look at [some docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list), we see that "This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2)". That's likely achieved using a method similar or equivalent to what songyuanyao showed.

Comment: @DevenTopiwala `std::list` implementation (in stdlibc++) uses *SFINAE* (as suggested in the other answer).

Comment: @DevenTopiwala fair point, I did not consider `std::list` but only looked at your code. Others properly pointed out, how `std::list` avoids this with SFINAE.